# Why is Dell currently trading above the buyout price?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-valuation

Dell is [going private at $13.65 per share](http://www.latimes.com/business/technology/la-fi-tn-dell-goes-private-20130205,0,7066492.story), so why is it trading at [$13.95 per share](https://www.google.com/finance?cid=153088) right now? Does anybody know when the buyout will actually go through? I can't seem to find that information anywhere.

Comment: see http://seekingalpha.com/article/1221841-why-i-m-buying-dell-at-14 - It appears the price can still move up from this figure

Answer (score 6):

Dividends would be a possible factor you are ignoring.  If Dell has another quarter or two to pay out dividends that could account for some of the difference there.

I don't think there is a confirmed date of when the deal is done yet other than around the end of Dell's second quarter which was in the LA Times link you cited.

---

There is also the potential for the terms of the deal to be revised that is another possibility here.  Have you examined other deals where a public company went private to see how the stock performed in the last few months before the deal closed?

Comment: +1 - although the dividend is 8 cents a quarter, tough to imagine the 30 premium is a bet the deal won't close for a year.