# Can a buyout announcement cause a short squeeze above the announced takeover price?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities, corporate-acquisition

Consider a company with heavily shorted stock. If that company puts itself up for sale and a friendly (shareholder approved) acquisition happens, can it result in a [short squeeze](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/shortsqueeze.asp) driving the price of the stock (of course, temporarily) above the agreed/announced takeover price?

Note that I don't mean the price of the stock being higher than the buyout price due to effects discussed in [Why is Dell currently trading above the buyout price?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20897/why-is-dell-currently-trading-above-the-buyout-price)

I am only interested if the price can spike up above the set limit because of the short squeeze effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, short covering can raise share price above the offered buy out price.  This occasionally occurs when the buy out price is significantly higher than current price and there's a gap up.

If there are no other companies rumored to be possibly offering a higher buy out price then share price will correct down to the buy out price as new shorters come in, hoping that the buy out offer is solid.

Comment: If only the original shorters could have waited a bit longer they could have taken the places of the subsequent shorters...

Comment: @Michael - Every trade has a buyer and  seller and one of them is almost always going to be able to  say "If I could only have waited a  bit longer".